# Mouse gives more clicks than I give

Tags: mouse

I'm currently having an issue with the mouse. It started after one of the latest updates, but not sure if it is related.

At first I thought it was an application issue, but after testing with a simple script something else is revealed. The case is that "mouse down" result in multiple mouse down/up/down etc.

The script, (sorry for the extra clutter with colors), is:

```
#!/bin/bash

xev -event button | awk '
    BEGIN {
        e = 0;
        t = 0;
        c[0] = "\033[31;1m"
        c[1] = "\033[36;1m"
    }
    /Press/   {e = 0; printf "down "}
    /Release/ {e = 1; printf "up   "}
    /time/ {
        printf "%s%8d %s\n", c[e], ($6 - t), strftime("%M:%S")
        t = $6 + 0
    }
'
```

Some samples showing the issue:

```
In reality: 1 down
down      191 51:12
up         16 51:12
down       36 51:12

In reality: 1 down
down     1532 52:21
up         48 52:21
down       16 52:21

In reality: 1 down
down     1580 53:03
up         16 53:03
down       16 53:03
up       1189 53:04 (yes, held down button here as well)
down       18 53:04
```

Have also seen the same with single clicks, as in, single clicks are spawned as double clicks as two down/up/down/up series of events are sent.

This is *not* a constant. I can do 10-20 clicks with no issue, then it is an issue for a couple of clicks, not for the next, and then perhaps an issue for the next 10.

---

My question is how I can further check if this is a software issue or HW issue? I have tried with different mouses, but the problem persist.

Have searched web for bugs but not found any, but google-foo (what ever is left of that) is not the best.

Comment: If the issue is still occurring after using different mice, it sounds like a software issue... Have you tried putting the mouse in a different port and testing?

Comment: @Peschke: Yes. Have tried several. But the issue prevails, for one, in xve. Secondly It is revealed in different software: FireFox, Chrome, LibreOffice, mpv, VIM, GIMP etc. Perhaps a driver issue? IDK.